# Why does test case 2 of the asterisk pyramid JSPerf test take so long?

Tags: javascript, performance

```
var elemText = document.getElementById("insert");
for (var k = 1; k <= 4; k++) {
  for (var j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
    elemText.innerHTML += ('*');
  };
  elemText.innerHTML += ('<br>');
};
```

Teardown:

`document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "";`

Is there a coding error? Is is just horribly inefficient (I think this unlikely to be the sole reason)? Is it something to do with the way the test is set up?

Comment: The second answer is just horribly inefficient. Working with `innerHTML` (especially many times in loop) takes more time than once targeting `textContent`.

Comment: Always post the relevant code **in the question itself**, don't just link. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a coding error?

Yes. You forgot to reinitialize the `<div>` in test #2. You need to empty it, just as you set `result = []` in test #1. Doing it in the teardown is not enough, and test #2 will generate much longer texts before clearing than test #1.

Also, your test cases have not the same result. Since you want to output `<br />` elements in test #1 as well, you would need to use `innerHTML` there, too. Your current code did output `<br>` literally as text.

[Improved test setup](http://jsperf.com/asterisk-pyramid/3)

> Is is just horribly inefficient?

Yes. Working with `innerHTML` is inefficient - it needs the HTML parser each time you assign to it, and you are doing it very often. Also, since you are using `+=` it needs to serialize the DOM each time.

Comment: It's in the teardown preparation code: `document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "";`

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: Ah, I didn't see that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Wk_of_Angmar: Yet, it does not happen after each of the snippet run, but only after each timed loop.